# Como aplicar autoFocus a un input React JS

Tags: reactjs

Quisiera aplicar el autofocus a un input pero he leido que solo se puede aplicar al momento de hacer el render, sera que se puede aplicar al momento de presionar un botton por ejemplo? agradezco desde ya la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

En dado caso alguien tenga este mismo inconveniente, esta fue la solucion
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/react-set-focus-on-input-after-render

Comment: Para que tu auto-respuesta sea de utilidad, debieras copiar la parte relevante de ese link en ésta.